# @media not working with width less than 1024px

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, percentage

I have a flex-box grid of divs.
I want to change width of that div (in %) depending on screen size.

My scss `@media`:

```css
   @media (max-width: 1023.9px) {
      width: 33.3333%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      width: 50%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 599px) {
      width: 100%;
    }

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
      width: 25%;
    }
```

But when I test that in Chrome's Responsive tool, I got only this:

Case of 500px width, It doesn't change,

[image: screenshot]
When I change my screen size to 1020, it's OK, `max-width: 1023.9px` is working. 
1200 is OK, `min-width: 1024px` is working. But less than 1024 - I get that strange things. What do I do wrong?

Generated css for my grid-class:

```css
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f6f6f6; }
  .image-grid .image-wrapper {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative; }
    .image-grid .image-wrapper::before {
      display: block;
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 88.23529%; }
    @media (max-width: 1023.9px) {
      .image-grid .image-wrapper {
        width: 33.3333%; } }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .image-grid .image-wrapper {
        width: 50%; } }
    @media (max-width: 599px) {
      .image-grid .image-wrapper {
        width: 100%; } }
    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
      .image-grid .image-wrapper {
        width: 25%; } }
```

Hmm, now It works fine when I resize my browser window, I normally get my 1 column with 550px and 2 columns with 700px. Question is answered, but in "Responsive" tool 550px and 700px still not working. Maybe I don't understand the tool.

Finally solved. The problem was totally dumb: I forgot adding `meta` tag, so Responsive tool didn't work properly. Don't forget about that important line. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: can you share the full generated CSS code? with the classes and everything

Comment: @TemaniAfif, edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every rule in CSS is able to override any previous rule to the same selector. So you just need to switch your code in order to get it working:

```
@media (max-width: 1023.9px) {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

// experimental
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  width: 100%;
}

//
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  width: 25%;
}
```

The reason why your rules override each other is because they all have the same selector and while `max-width: 599px` is accurate and correct, the later appearing `max-width: 1023.9px` is it, too and thus it’s overriding the previous `width: 100%;` from the `max-width: 599px` media query.

And a side note here: Use integer values only for media queries. There is no screen in the world, which has `.9` or even `.5` pixels.

Comment: It definitely is. An example (which just resizes an image according to your media queries): https://jsfiddle.net/y7vnsb9q/ Please review your code.

Comment: I reviewed your example, and reviewed my page, It really works. It works fine when I resize my browser, but in "responsive" I still have that issue.

Answer (score -1):

CSS is the acronym of Cascade Style Sheet.

This means that rules are matched in a cascade fashion. If you have a viewport width between 1000 and 1024, the 33.3333% is the last that matches and it will be applied, overriding all the previous.

Once you know it, you can change your code in a proper way. If you don't want to re-think your code, you can prevent the overriding using `!important`.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

> Warning: Using `!important` is a bad practice, the reason is [here](https://www.developeracademy.io/blog/css-important-rule-use-correctly/)

Comment: Ok, with 1000px your solution is OK. But how can I test my code with less than 1000px?

Comment: @Cristian Traina Why are you showing a bad practice instead of the best practice, which you even mentioned? This way, I don’t think this is a good answer, as your sample code is not the recommended way.

Comment: @KittMedia Because I can't explain the best practice, since it's not clear what he's trying to achieve. If he can't change his code, as often happens, then the "bad practice" is the only solution

Comment: I agree on the fact that `!imporant` must be used the least possible